# returning a multidimensional array with explicit return type in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class which has a member defined as:

```
float U[2][2];
```

Now I have an accessor function and I would like to return a reference to this array. So, I have something like:

```
const float & [2][2] mat() const
{
    return U;
}
```

Is there a way to return it using this kind o syntax rather than pointer syntax (I think it makes things more explicit).

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of C arrays, it makes about everything easier.

Comment: Prefer `std::array`, but another option is to use a typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's awkward, but:

```
const float (&mat() const)[2][2]
{
    return U;
}
```

Using a typedef or `decltype` might be better, eg:

```
const decltype(U) &mat() const { return U; }
```

or:

```
using mat22 = float[2][2];
const mat22 &mat() const { return U; }
```

(this latter one as suggested by Daniel H. in comments).

or, in C++14, even just:

```
const auto &mat() const { return U; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I would do something like `using matrix22 = float[2][2]; matrx22 const& mat() const { return U; }`.